# Eratosthenes sieve and MPI

Tags: c++, c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, mpi

I wrote this [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) with MPI, but I'm not sure if it's good enough. Should I use `MPI_Scatter` and `MPI_Gather` instead of collecting arrays of separate processes in the root process?

Also, I'm not sure if I call

```
printArray(myArray, (N/size)-1);
```

right, where `myArray` is an array of pointers. GCC gives a warning at this point.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 60

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
long timeCPU;
int rank, size, k, i, v, n, scatterSize;
int **tmpArray, *myArray, firstElement, lastElement;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

if(N%size != 0)
{
    MPI_Finalize();
    printf("ERROR!");
    exit(0);
}

firstElement = (rank*N)/size;
lastElement = floor(((rank+1)*N)/size);
myArray = (int*) (malloc(((N/size)-1)*sizeof(int)));

for(i=0, v=firstElement+2; i<=(N/size)-1; i++, v++)
{
    myArray[i] = v;
}
    printArray(myArray, (N/size)-1);
/* All processes have to execute above code first */
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

k = 2;

do
{
    markMultiples(k, myArray, lastElement-firstElement);
    k = nextNumber(k, myArray, lastElement-firstElement);
    MPI_Bcast(&k, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
while(k*k <=N);

MPI_Send(myArray, (N/size)-1, MPI_INT, 0, 50, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (rank == 0)
{
    // Initialize 2D array
    tmpArray = (int**) (malloc(size*sizeof(int)));
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        tmpArray[i] = (int*) (malloc(((N/size)-1)*sizeof(int)));
    }

    // Gather from every process his own array
    for (i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        MPI_Recv(tmpArray[i], (N/size)-1, MPI_INT, i, 50, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printArray(tmpArray[i], (N/size)-1);
        printf("-----------------------------------------\n");
    }

    // Build 1d array with primes - TODO

}

//printArray(array, lastElement-firstElement);
free(myArray);
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}

int nextNumber(int k, int *array, int n)
{
int i;

for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    if(array[i] > k)
        return array[i];
}
return -1;
}

void markMultiples(int k, int *array, int n)
{
int i;

for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    if(array[i] % k == 0 && array[i] != k)
    {
        array[i] = -1;
    }
}
}

void printArray(int *array, int n)
{
int i;

for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: My advice: split up that main function.

Comment: It definitely is a good idea to use the collectives offered by MPI instead of re-implementing them yourself.

Answer (score 11):

Since you tagged this question [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) I assume you would like a C++ approach also.

I would suggest using `std::vector<int>` rather than an `int*` and `malloc`. Using the vector will give you a number of useful advantages over a normal pointer, for example, memory management is greatly simplified, and there is no need to worry about how big an `int` is. With `vector`, the order of all elements is guaranteed to be contiguous.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int nextNumber(int k, const std::vector<int> &array, int n)
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator i = std::find_if(array.begin(), array.begin() + n, std::bind2nd(std::greater<int>(), k));

    return (i == array.end() ? -1 : *i);
}

bool isMultiple(int a, int b)
{
    return (a % k == 0) && (a != k);
}

void markMultiples(int k, std::vector<int> &array, int n)
{
    std::replace_if(array.begin(), array.begin() + n, std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(isMultiple), k), -1);
}


void printArray(const std::vector<int> &array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "array[" << i << "] = " << array[i] << std::endl;
}
```

#### Disclaimer:

I am not very good at C++, so you may want to take this advice with a teaspoon of salt.

Answer (score 6):

- This error message reveals nothing about the actual error:

  > ```
  > if(N%size != 0)
  > {
  >     MPI_Finalize();
  >     printf("ERROR!");
  >     exit(0);
  > }
  > ```

  Just displaying "ERROR!" won't tell the user *what* this exact error is and/or *why* it has happened.  Yes, it's certainly important to make sure the input size and number of processes are divisible in MPI to maintain load balance, but the user *must* still know about this so that either input can be adjusted accordingly.

  It may also help others (and yourself) to display the computed portion size, whether or not this error has occurred.  If you get an unreasonable value (usually if the portion size cannot fit inside an `int` (overflow), which is a commonly used size type by the MPI functions), then the user will know about this and will attempt to fix it for next time.

  This error, and any others, should be printed to `stderr` via `fprintf()` instead.

  As this is *not* a successful exit, you should use a different exit/return value other than `0`.  This may ideally depend on the language you'll be using (this uses C and C++), but it may be good to use `1` (or `EXIT_FAILURE`) for this.

  Finally, you can just have process 0 display the error so that it's displayed only once (any normal output should just be printed by this process).  Of course, all of the processes should still call `MPI_Finalize()` and `exit()`/`return()`.
- Regarding memory allocation:

  You allocate memory for `tmpArray`, but never deallocate it.  Since it's only allocated by process 0, just have that process handle the deallocation, so that it's done only once (very important).

  ```
  if (rank == 0) free(tmpArray);
  ```

  You may also consider terminating the program if *any* allocation has failed:

  ```
  if (myArray == NULL) // nullptr if using C++11
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "could not allocate array\n");
      MPI_Finalize();
      return EXIT_FAILURE; // or use any suitable non-zero error value
  }
  ```
- Regarding cleanliness:

  Indentation is inconsistent in some places.  Also, you don't indent entire function bodies, which could greatly hurt readability if one cannot tell where some code belongs.

  Some lines, such as this one:

  > ```
  > for(i=0, v=firstElement+2; i<=(N/size)-1; i++, v++)
  > ```

  could use a little more whitespace between some operators:

  ```
  for (i = 0, v = firstElement+2; i <= (N/size)-1; i++, v++)
  ```

  It's mostly up to you, but it may be clearer to at least have the equality and assignment operators separated to help identify the operands.